# UITableView -setContentOffset stopped working in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have been using -

```
[tableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO]
```

in iOS6 to insure that my tableViews where positioned at the top of the view.  I have been refactoring for iOS7 and it seems have stopped working.  I have had to replace with -

```
[tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:NO];
```

which works with in both cases.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Could it be something else? I'm using the first approach in an iOS 7 app without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `scrollToRowAtIndexPath`:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```